# Maildir and users

Tags: email, pop3, maildir

I have pop3 local server. I want to use mail storage - Maildir format. And i have question:

Maildir structure:

```
       Maildir
tmp      cur     new
```

Is it for one user? If i have 2 users in my pop3 server, how can pop3 server explain to mail client where first user mailbox and where second user mailbox?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this structure is for one user.

The structure for the whole domain will be for example:

```
/home/vuser/your_domain/
user1     user2      user3
```

Inside each user dir, you the structure of `Maildir`. Usually, the email servers such as `courier` are very flexible. You can customise the structure if you want. The prefix `/home/vuser` can be any path.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is one mailbox in Maildir format. POP3 server shows to client only one mailbox, so you should configure it to use one maildir for first user and another for second.